# Modify a index.php from an .iso

Tags: linux, testing, vmware, iso

Hei guys,
Im working on a pentesting project, and I wanted to know if there is a way of modify an existing index.php wich is inside an iso.
I get my iso form

> https://pentesterlab.com/exercises/web_for_pentester

And i want to modify the index.php that it generate, due to be able to just get an exercise on this index.
Anyone know if is posible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`mkdir /mnt/iso
mount -o loop your.iso /mnt/iso`

Copy your files to some directory and make your edits. Then repack the iso using `genisoimage`

`genisoimage -o yournew.iso directory`

Comment: I get the files, but all of them seems to be .txt, cant find the index.php that it renders on the ip